# Mac OSX Terminal: how to fade old commands and stdout?

Tags: macos, terminal

One common feature of the Mac OSX terminal I find myself wanting is some way to display old commands and printed outputs a different ANSI text color so that when running for programs with long outputs, I don't have to hunt for a particular separator. (instead, I can just set old printouts to gradually fade as they move further back in terminal history)

Is it possible to do this on Mac OSX?

Thanks

Comment: It's not what you asked for, but are you aware of the "marks" feature? By default, Terminal marks each prompt line and you move among them with items from the Edit > Navigate menu. You can also select the output between marks by holding Shift as you navigate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, no you can not.

I suggest make this a suggestion to Apple at [www.apple.com/feedback/](http://www.apple.com/feedback/)